# GridView row values not changed after update

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview, datatable

I want to update row in `GridView` with this code but after editing `GridView` not changes:

```
protected void res_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
        GridViewRow row =res.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["name"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[6].Controls[0])).Text;
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["dewey"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).Text;
        *dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["subject"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text;
        Session["dt"] = dt;
        res.EditIndex = -1;
        res.DataSource = dt;
        res.DataBind();
    }
```

my `Page_Load`:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dt= Converter.ListBooks(new classes.Book().GetAll());
            Session["dt"] = dt;
            res.DataSource = dt;
            res.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            dt=(DataTable)Session["dt"];
            res.DataSource = dt;
            res.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

for example I changed line that have * to this:

```
dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["subject"] = "tx";
```

and after edit "subject" column changed to "tx", so I don't know why `((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text` return `TextBox`'s text before edit?

Comment: remove the else part in page_load, you really should not bind it there. please bind the gridview in events that raise the postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're calling **DataBind();** method each time page refreshed (POST or GET), let me explain more if user put the new value in the TextBox and click on update button to trigger **res_RowUpdating** even **Page_Load** will fire and bind the Gird with database values which is the old values and neglect the user input value.

Comment: I removed `res.DataBind()` in `else` block and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changes are done but the form is not being updated.

Try putting gridview control inside an Update Panel Control and call UpdatePanel.Update().

When you work with a web control, what you see can be different from what actually is because changes in data are not autoupdated in the presentation layer.

To solve this "problem" you can make a postback (retrieving everything) of the whole page, but this is like killing a fly with a bazooka because you do not need everything, just what has been updated, so for this purpose there are several tool that allow you to make partial updates, for example the AJAX control: UpdatePanel.

Hope it helps.

Update: Call the AcceptChanges() method on the DataTable and erase the else branch on the Page_Load after if(!PostBack)

Comment: this is not my problem.I changed question title that was unclear.

Comment: So your problem now is not changes being applied but getting Text from some rows you want?

Comment: my problem is that `((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text` not returning edited value

Comment: Could be related to the controls you have defined inside the grid, for example, if you defined a textbox inside the column you are trying to get, the way of accessing that value would be: ((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0].Controls[0])).Text. You can try finding the proper way of access with Visual Studio, in the Inmediate Window try pasting the code I just wrote you. If it does not work, try copying the gridview complete definition (aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you just need to rebind the grid

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `else` part in your `page_load`.

Should do it for you.

You are binding the Grid every time there is a `postback` which is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `AcceptChanges()` method of the `DataTable` and then bind the `GridView`.